# Some simple questions about mips and memory?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am a student learning mips and I have a few questions about how memory access and loading works.

In our first homework we are given this macro to use

```
sw $a0, numargs
lw $t0, 0($a1)
sw $t0, arg1
lw $t0, 4($a1)
sw $t0, arg2
lw $t0, 8($a1)
sw $t0, arg3
```

This macro's job is to get the arguments we load into mips. It work's but I was more curious on how it work as out professor never really explained it and just told us to use it.

So in the "program arguments" field I'll enter three arguments. Does MIPS instantly use a0 as the number of arguments and that's why we can store that in our own variable?

Then each argument has its own memory address. Does the register $a1 combine all the last 4 bits of the memory addresses of the arguments? That way we jump 4 bits every time to get to a new argument and then store that argument in our own variable.

Also load word confuses me a little bit

For example in this snippet of code

```
lw $t0, arg2        
lb $t1, 3($t0)      
move $a0, $t1
addi $v0, $0, 11
syscall
```

It works correctly. I set to t1 to be the last byte of t0 (thus the last character of the argument) and it prints correctly. So if the argument is 1234, it prints 4.

However when I try to add

```
sll $t0, $t0, 8
```

after the first line, it doesn't work. I don't understand why. I am shifting $t0 by 8 bits. So the last byte is erased and "3" should be the last byte and what is printed. But it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

That particular macro is not standard practice for MIPS programming, and is only useful for this particular class.

The sequence:

```
lw $t0, arg2
lb $t1, 3($t0)
```

does not do what you think it does.  `lw $t0, arg2` loads the memory value at location `arg2` into `$t0`. So if the memory word at location `arg2` had the value 1024 (decimal), `$t0` would be set to 1024.

`lb $t1, 3($t0)` loads the memory byte at the address contained in `$t0` and puts it into `$t1`. If `$t0` contained the value 1024, then the memory byte at addess 1024 + 3 = 1027 would be put into `$t1`.

Adding `sll $t0, $t0, 8` after the `lw` would change the value of `$t0` from 1024 to 262144. Then the `lb` would attempt to read the memory byte at 262144 + 3, which your program is probably not allowed to read.